# Serialize a list of objects in JSON C# and deserialize it on Android

Tags: c#, android, json

I need to serialize a list of objects in JSON C# and deserialize it on Android.

C#

```
public string SerializeData(List<SymbolsInfo> dave)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jss.Serialize(dave);
        return json;
    }
```

Serialization -- OK. How i can to deserialize this list on android ?

```
[Serializable]
public partial class SymbolsInfo
{
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SVolume { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime SDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling web service or REST service from android?

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis, No

Comment: There are all kinds of libraries for deserializing JSON in Java.  You could use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), among many others listed at [Json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: then how you are getting json object in android from c#? any other way you are using?

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis, Server sends a json by tcp sockets

Comment: Do i need to create class SymbolsInfo in android project ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge

- Android doesn't support auto JSON deserialisation, and the only JAVA library that I know is Jackson, check FasterXML/jackson at github, which I don't think it's suitable for your android case.
- The common solution is to read the http response and then parse it manually using JSONOBject / JSONArray according to your response. This link contains good explanation about how to use these object, [check decode JSON section](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)
- About doing the http request and current the response, android support two http client. for more details check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,
Use ObjectMapper class from jackson library

Receive data over socket and pass that string to following program

```
jsonData="{\"StringRecivedOverTheSocket":\"OK\"}";
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();



List<SymbolsInfo> list= objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, List<SymbolsInfo>.class);
```